# Nginx - 413 Request Entity too Large with configuration

Tags: php, nginx, web, configuration

This question is asked many times. I have gone through those answers and implemented those changes in php.ini or nginx.conf. Restarted the nginx as well as php but still the problem is there. Here is the config of my nginx config

```
http {
server_tokens off;

include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

include       conf.d/*.conf;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default     "upgrade";
}

server {
    listen        80 default_server;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    sendfile on;
    client_header_timeout 60;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    client_body_buffer_size 20M;
    client_body_timeout   60;
    keepalive_timeout     60;
    gzip                  off;
    gzip_comp_level       4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
    include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
}
```

Could anyone please let me know what else I can do to make this problem go away?

Comment: This question needs more clarity, like what type of request is causing this error.